# How can I bring tex-mode's sexp navigation to AucTeX?

Tags: auctex, sexp, tex-mode

I generally prefer AucTeX over the built-in tex-mode, but one thing that is much better in tex-mode is navigation by s-expression. Namely, in tex-mode, `forward-sexp` (`C-M-f`) treats LaTeX environments as s-expressions; with the point right before `\begin{foo}`, `forward-sexp` will take you to after the corresponding `\end{foo}`. Other sexp based functions also do the right thing, for example `backward-up-list` (`C-M-u`) will take you to the enclosing `\begin{foo}`.

How can I get this functionality in AucTeX?

(I noticed tex-mode defines a `latex-forward-sexp` and sets `forward-sexp-function` to that function. I tried loading tex-mode after AucTeX and evaluating `(setq-local latex-forward-sexp #'latex-forward-sexy)` but that didn't seem to change the behavior of `forward-sexp` in the AucTeX buffer.)

Comment: AUCTeX provides `LaTeX-find-matching-begin` (`C-M-a`) and `LaTeX-find-matching-end` (`C-M-e`).  Have you tried them?

Comment: Those are great, @ArashEsbati, and I *was* unaware of them. This goes a long way to satisfying my sexp-navigation needs, but `forward-sexp` in tex-mode also knows about `$math$`, `\(math\)` and `\[math\]`.

Comment: The package `latex-extra` on `melpa` adds support for that kind of navigation to auctex

Comment: I wish AUCTeX could simply re-use the functionality of the built-in tex-mode instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After stepping through the `latex-forward-sexp-1` function from tex-mode (long live `edebug`!), I figured out why it works in tex-mode buffers, but not in AucTeX: it's because tex-mode gives the backslash syntax class `/`, but AucTeX gives it syntax class `\`!

So, I've simply added this to my AucTeX configuration to get tex-mode's better sexp-navigation:

```
(autoload #'latex-forward-sexp "tex-mode" nil t)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\\ "/" LaTeX-mode-syntax-table)
(defun fix-LaTeX-sexp ()
   (setq-local forward-sexp-function #'latex-forward-sexp))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'fix-LaTeX-sexp)
```

(I like how wrong it feels to load tex-mode in my AucTeX configuration. :P)

I'd love it if someone comes up with a different approach.

Comment: Changing the syntax class for ``?\\`` globally in `LaTeX-mode-syntax-table` looks like asking for trouble to me.  Why not using `with-syntax-table` to change the syntax class locally and execute your function?  The original syntax table is restored afterwards.

Comment: @ArashEsbati, it doesn't seem like anything broke in this case, but you're right that in general it is safer to make the change locally.

Answer (score 0):

The package https://github.com/ultronozm/tex-parens.el is motivated by questions like this concerning sexp/list-based navigation in AUCTeX